# The letter $\wp$; Name & origin?

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, terminology, notation, elliptic-functions

1. Do you think the letter $\wp$ has a name? It may depend on community - the language, region, speciality, etc, so if you don't mind, please be specific about yours. (Mainly I'd like to know the English names,  if any, but other information is welcome.) If yes, when and how did you come to know it? When, how, and how often do you mention it? (See below.)
2. What's the origin of the letter?

In computing, various names, many of which are bad, have been given to $\wp$. See [my answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/278932/56062).

Background: (Sorry for being a bit chatty.)

Originally I [raised a related question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Weierstrass_p#Cleanup) at Wikipedia. The user [Momotaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Momotaro) answered that in math community it's called "Weierstrass-p". Momotaro also gave a nice reference to the book [The Brauer-Hasse-Noether Theorem in Historical Perspective](http://www.worldcat.org/title/brauer-hasse-noether-theorem-in-historical-perspective/oclc/990614315) by Peter Roquette. The author's claim supports Momotaro. (The episode in the book about the use of $\wp$ by Hasse and Emmy Noether is very interesting - history amuses -  but it's off topic. Read the above link to Wikipedia. :)

However I'm not completely sure yet, because the occasions on which the letter's name becomes a topic must be quite limited. For example perhaps in the classroom a professor draws $\wp$, and students giggle by witnessing such a weird symbol and mastery of handwriting it; then the professor solemnly announces "this letter is called Weierstrass-p", like that? And "Weierstrass-p" is never an alias of the p-function?

After reading Momotaro's comment, I think I've read somewhere that the letter was invented by Weierstrass himself, but my memory about it is quite vague. Does anyone know something about it? Is it a mere folklore, or any reference?

I don't think mathoverflow is a place for votes, but if it were, I'd like one: "Have you ever heard of the name of the letter $\wp$?

Slightly off-topic, about the p-function's name in Japanese; In Japanese, the names of the Latin alphabets are mostly of English origin, エー, ビー, シー... (eh, bee, cee, etc.) But $\wp$-function is called ペー (peh), indicating its German origin. See e.g. [岩波 数学公式 III, p34, footnote 2](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4000055097/) I don't know the *name* of the letter in Japanese. (In fact, most non-English European languages read "p" as "peh"...)

**EDIT** Examples of typography in some early literature (off-topic, but interesting):

- First see the [excellent comment below](https://mathoverflow.net/a/278138) by [Francois Ziegler](https://mathoverflow.net/users/19276/francois-ziegler)
- $\wp$ that looks like the original (?) and today's glyph:

  - *Elliptische Functionen. Theorie und geschichte.* (sic) (1890) by [Alfred Enneper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Enneper) with [Felix Müller](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_M%C3%BCller_(Mathematiker)), [p60](https://archive.org/stream/elliptischefunc00mlgoog#page/n85/mode/2up). [The first ed](https://archive.org/details/elliptischefunct00ennerich) (1876) by Enneper alone does not seem to mention $\wp$-function.
  - *A Course of Modern Analysis* (1902) by Whittaker, 1st ed, [p322](https://archive.org/stream/acoursemodernan00watsgoog#page/n342/mode/2up). (Famous Whittaker & Watson, but the 1st ed was by Whittaker alone.)
- Similar to Kurrent/Sütterlin (see [the answer below](https://mathoverflow.net/a/278168) by [Manfred Weis](https://mathoverflow.net/users/31310/manfred-weis)) lowercase p. All were published by the publisher Gauthier-Villars in Paris, in French:

  - *Traité des fonctions elliptiques et de leurs applications*  (1886) by [Georges Henri Halphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges_Henri_Halphen), [p 355](https://archive.org/stream/traitedesfonctio01halprich#page/n367/mode/2up).
  - *Éléments de la Théorie des Fonctions Elliptiques* (1893) by [Jules Tannery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jules_Tannery) and [Jules Molk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jules_Molk), vol 1, [page 156](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.377060/2015.377060.Elements-De#page/n163/mode/2up).
  - *Principes de la théorie des fonctions elliptiques et applications* (1897) by Emile Lacour and [Paul Appell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Appell), [p 22](https://archive.org/stream/principesdelath00appegoog#page/n41/mode/2up).
- BTW [Abramowitz & Stegun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abramowitz_Stegun) uses $\mathscr{P}$. Wow. See [p 629](https://web.archive.org/web/20120203051817/http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_629.htm).

Comment: In an era where all mathematics is written in English, it is easy to forget that the use of German script letters for mathematical notation was once common throughout the German mathematical literature.

Comment: I never heard the *letter* called "the Weierstrass p"; I only ever heard the *function* called "the Weierstrass p-function." I've heard the letter called "curly p."

Comment: @GerryMyerson: It's a very good point now, but there is the [subtlety](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6104/who-first-considered-the-f-in-fx-as-an-object-in-itself-and-who-decided-t) that 19th century people would overwhelmingly call $\wp(u)$, **not** $\wp$, the function. With rare exceptions, they were queasy about $\wp$ alone being anything more than a letter. So a name for $\wp$ (which I'm not saying that had, but maybe *Pe*) would initially be a letter name, not a function name.

Comment: The fact that the $\TeX$ name is ``\wp`` may be influencing some people to refer to the letter as "Weierstrass p."

Comment: I learned the symbol $\wp$ for Weierstrass's elliptic function when I was a graduate student in the late 1960's, so long before TeX. Since then, I've seen this symbol used universally for that same function. I've also seen it used occasionally for "power set", but I suspect that's the result of confusion with the more standard notation $\mathcal P$ for power set

Comment: @AndreasBlass In Wikipedia, $\wp$ as a power set symbol is common [(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=wp%20powerset) [(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=wp%20%22power%20set%22), to my surprise. My guess is that it's because in Wikipedia you can't use \mathscr to date.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Apparently first introduced by Weierstrass in [Winter 1862/63 lectures](http://archive.org/stream/encyklomath202encyrich#page/n272/mode/1up) published by H. A. Schwarz (1881, [1885](https://archive.org/stream/acq9098.0001.001.umich.edu#page/10), [1892](https://archive.org/stream/fomundezumderfun00weierich#page/10), [1893](https://archive.org/stream/formelnundlehr01weierich#page/n21)), §9:

> Mit der **Sigma**-Function $\mathfrak Su$ ist die **Pe**-Function $\wp u=\wp(u\mid\omega,\omega')=\wp(u;g_2,g_3)$ durch die Gleichung
>   $$
> \wp u=-\frac{d^2}{du^2}\log\mathfrak S u=\frac{(\mathfrak S'u)^2-\mathfrak S u\mathfrak S''u}{\mathfrak S^2u}
> $$
>   verbunden. (...)

The letter and a reference to Schwarz's notes also appear on the first page of Weierstrass's paper *Zur Theorie der elliptischen Functionen* ([1882](http://bibliothek.bbaw.de/bibliothek-digital/digitalequellen/schriften/anzeige/index_html?band=10-sitz/1882-1&seite:int=465)). Attribution in e.g. (Schwarz student) H. Hancock's *Lectures on the Theory of Elliptic Functions* ([1910](https://archive.org/stream/lecturestheorell00hancrich#page/n340)), p. 309:

> (...) the function which we thus have was called by Weierstrass the *Pe-function* and denoted by
>   $$
> \wp(u)\qquad\text{or more simply}\qquad\wp u
> $$

or R. Godement's *Analysis I* ([2004](https://books.google.com/books?id=yqkSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA181&dq=%22the+famous+function%22)), p. 181:

> (...) the famous function
>   $$
> \wp(u)=1/u^2+\sum_{\omega\ne0}\left[1/(u-\omega)^2-1/\omega^2\right]
> $$
>   of Weierstrass (it already appeared in Eisenstein), with a $p$ which smacks of the gothic, of the italic and of the cursive, chosen by the inventor<sup>65</sup> and retained by posterity. (...)
>
> ---
>
> <sup>65</sup> His biography in the DSB tells us that in the course of his fourteen years of high-school teaching he had to teach mathematics, physics, German, botany, geography, history, gymnastics “and even calligraphy”.

**Note added:** While I don’t know of a handwritten specimen by Weierstrass himself (asked about in comments by @NateEldredge and @ManfredWeis), there are a few in lecture notes of S. Pincherle who [had studied with Weierstrass](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Pincherle.html) in Berlin: ([1899-1900, Chap. XXII](https://archive.org/stream/lezionisullateor00pincuoft#page/14)).

Comment: $\mathfrak S_\Lambda(z),z \in \mathbb{C}$ is his [sigma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_functions#Weierstrass_sigma-function), the Weierstrass product associated to a lattice $\Lambda$

Comment: It might be interesting to ask what was the sequence that lead him to (regularization terms of) the Weierstrass product, if it was the points of a lattice or if he was interested in something else.

Comment: Let me add that in German "pe" is "how to pronounce 'P'", i.e. the equivalent of the English ['pi] (in phonetic transcription). Therefore, at the time of Weierstrass, $\wp$ was nothing more than a nicely calligraphied hand-written letter "P", something like $\mathcal P$ or $\mathscr P$. It was only later that it became a special symbol by itself.

Comment: Did Weierstrass write this $\wp$ significantly differently from how he wrote other instances of the letter $p$?

Comment: +1, yes.  I first learned this (perhaps from Ahlfors) as: "the Weierstrass pe function".

Answer (score 12):

The Weierstrass *p* has a strong similarity to [p in the Sütterlin alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%BCtterlin), which had been developed in Prussia and, as Weierstrass worked in Berlin (the capital of Prussia), it may well be that that is the origin of the letter.

Books were printed in [Fraktur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur), where the *p* looks quite normal, i.e., quite different from a handwritten Sütterlin *p* which could explain, why it hasn't been replaced in the publication of Amandus Schwarz.

But I am not a historian, so this answer is a bit speculative, albeit reasonable.

Comment: Though similarity is a subjective matter, I'm afraid the $\wp$ letter doesn't look to me like Sütterlin. However I found an example of Sütterlin-like lowercase p (but published in Paris in French!) Search for "Sütterlin" in my edited question.

Comment: @teikakazura No, not Sütterlin but Kurrent (I saw it in my father's handwriting when a child).

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. in Kurrent writing of the capital letter P starts from upper left and there is no inflection point before entering the loop; the capital letter K however starts from the right and has an inflection point before the loop. This isn't meant to rule out the explanation that the origin of $\wp$ is Kurrent - it only is meant to indicate that questions still remain. What is desparately missing is a handwritten text from Weierstrass himself.

Comment: If one looks at a [Kurrent alphabet from 1865](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Kurrentschrift#/media/File:Deutsche_Kurrentschrift.svg), one sees, that the small letter $p$ is written with two loops, the top one first and then the bottom one. It might be that Weierstrass switched that order (maybe because that allowed faster writing).

Comment: Or someone not familiar with Kurrent mixed up the order of the loops, thus 'inventing' the $\wp$

Comment: @ManfredWeis Thank you. In fact my father was a perfect German speaker and writer but, maybe, his gothic handwriting, coming from family tradition, was mixed. It looked like Weierstrass  _p_ only when the letter was isolated, when not (ligature with the preceding letter) it showed an upgoing ligature indicating that he was writing the bottom loop first.

Comment: @ManfredWeis ... and the ligature with the following letter was crossing the upper loop.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. if your father also changed the order of the loops, then probably also for reasons of speed or because the official way is too awkward. A similar effect can be observed when people try to write the '&' or the '@' sign; I've seen the most adventurous creations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64009/discussion-between-duchamp-gerard-h-e-and-manfred-weis).

Answer (score 10):

My own answer, about the name of the letter $\wp$. Mostly in *computing*, with little math. (Lengthy)

## Summary

In computing, the letter $\wp$ has been plagued with a plethora of inappropriate names. I guess "Weierstrass p" is one of such  names that some standard created, and has been copied without much scrutiny. I suspect that ISO-8879 in 1986 was the root of all evil.

Names and references that survive in latest standards are:

- `\wp`: TeX
- `script capital p` (wrong) and `weierstrass elliptic function` (alias): Unicode
- `&weierp;`: HTML (and XML?)

## Unicode

Unicode is not directly related to my question, but it is important behind the scenes, so a good point to start.

#### Basics

In Unicode the letter $\wp$ is given the codepoint U+2118 in the block "letterlike symbols", named "script capital p". But in fact it's lowercase. There's also an official alias "weierstrass elliptic function".

[Unicode Technical Note #27](http://www.unicode.org/notes/tn27/) regrets this misnomer:

> Should have been called *calligraphic small p* or *Weierstrass elliptic function symbol*, which is what it is used for. It is not a capital "P" at all. A formal alias correcting this to WEIERSTRASS ELLIPTIC FUNCTION has been defined.

[The first version](http://www.unicode.org/notes/tn27/tn27-1.html) of Technical Note #27 in 2006 was a bit more emphatic

> Should have been called *calligraphic small p* or **perhaps even** *Weierstrass elliptic function symbol*, which is what it is used for. It's not a capital "P" at all.

(Boldification is done by me.)

#### Unicode 1.0 (1991)

Unicode 1.0 (1991) defined the letter, and the [name was](http://www.unicode.org/Public/reconstructed/1.0.0/UnicodeData.txt) "script p". It was also called "weierstrass elliptic function". (See Footnote)

#### Unicode 2 (1996) screwed it up

They gave wrong names. *As seen later, this change matters for us.* From the file [Nameslist](http://www.unicode.org/Public/2.0-Update/NamesList-1.txt):

```
2118  SCRIPT CAPITAL P
      = per
      = power set
      = Weierstrass elliptic function
```

(All of them were legitimate names. See also the file [index](http://www.unicode.org/Public/2.0-Update/Index-1.txt).) 
Alas, power set; $\wp$ is *lowercase*. (But what's "per"? According to Wiktionary's entry "[per](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/per#Synonyms)" the preposition "per" used to be written sometimes with a script letter "p". An example can be found in 1911 Encyclopædia Britannica. See [Wikisource](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/1911_Encyclop%C3%A6dia_Britannica/Abbreviation#per) or [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/EncyclopaediaBritannicaDict.a.s.l.g.i.11thed.chisholm.1910-1911-1922.33vols/01.EncycBrit.11th.1910.v.1.A-AND.#page/n66/mode/1up))

Teminology note: The file "NamesList" maps from the codepoint (letter itself) to their names, the main one and aliases, if any. "Index" is the inverse mapping.

(Paranoiac detail: In Unicode 2.1, they changed its writing direction from "Other neutral" to "Left-to-right" See [here](http://www.unicode.org/Public/2.1-Update2/diff212v214.txt). For writing directionos see [this](http://www.unicode.org/Public/2.1-Update2/diff212v214.txt.).

#### Unicode 3.0 (1999)

In 3.0, two wrong names "per" and "power set" can't be seen in [Nameslist](http://www.unicode.org/Public/3.0-Update/NamesList-3.0.0.txt), but they still exist in [Index](http://www.unicode.org/Public/3.0-Update/Index-3.0.0.txt). Wow. They still remained in [3.2 Index](http://www.unicode.org/Public/3.2-Update/)

But not sure if this removal was officially announced

Unicode never changes the main names once they are given, so "script capital p" will stay for ever.

#### Unicode 4.0 (2003)

In Unicode [4.0](http://www.unicode.org/Public/4.0-Update/), it seems the index file was abolished. So it's finally settled to be "script capital p" and "weierstrass elliptic function".

#### Unicode 6.1 (2012)

Finally in Unicode [6.1](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.1.0/), the meaning of aliases were clarified. "weierstrass elliptic function" of U+2118 was [defined](http://www.unicode.org/Public/6.1.0/ucd/NameAliases.txt) to be "correction".

## Knuth's book (1986)

*Computer Modern Typeface* [(google books link)](https://books.google.com/books?id=CwdUAAAAMAAJ&q=weierstrass+isbn:0201134462&dq=weierstrass+isbn:0201134462&hl=en&sa=X&) by Don Knuth was published in 1986.

In p 26, there's a line *there are special symbols like Weierstrass's ‘p’ (℘)*. However, in the index in p 580, there's only the entry "Weierstrass, Karl Theodor Wilhelm", pointing to pp 26, 233 and 235, and the entry "Weierstrass'p" is not there. So I guess Knuth did **not** mean that "Weierstrass'p" was the name of the symbol.

## Old ISO, MathML, XML... true culprit?

Section summary: "Weierstrass p" was introduced sometime, but not sure exactly when. It has becoming obsolete, but not completely yet.

In HTML, you can write $\wp$ by escaping as `&weierp;`. Dunno other markup languages.

In [MathML 1.01 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-MathML/toc.html) (1998), $\wp$ is given the name "weierp", of which description is **"Weierstrass p"** and the alias "wp". [See here](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-MathML/chap6/ISOAMSOe1.html). The letter derived from "ISOamso", but I can't be sure if the name came from ISOamso, too. The status of the latest MathML, 3.0, will be stated at the end of this section.

ISOamso ("Added Math Symbols: Ordinary", has nothing to do with AMS :)
is a part of [SGML = ISO 8879:1986](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8879) in 1986, according to [this](https://www.w3.org/2003/entities/2007/isoamso.ent).
When the first MathML was under construction, ISO 10646 (roughly speaking Unicode itself, but its counterpart in ISO) were apparently not there. [See this](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-MathML/chapter6.html#sec6.2.2). They had to gather letters from various standards.

HTML is worse: I couldn't find any entity specification about $\wp$ in HTML 1 - 3. (In very rough translation, entity = letter. See [this intro](http://www.landofcode.com/html-tutorials/html-entities.php)) In HTML4 (1999), it is [defined as](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html#h-24.3)

> <!ENTITY weierp   CDATA "&#8472;" -- script capital P = power set = Weierstrass p, U+2118 ISOamso -->

Because HTML4 has been used so long (it's still in use), this wrong sepcification has spreaded widely. See below.

In HTML5 (2014), the word "entity" was abolished. "Character entity references" was change to "Character references", and the term "Named entities" was replaced with "Named character references". [See this](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5-pubnotes/). "Weierp" seems to have lost peculiarity up to HTML4; it's simply U+2118, and that's all. [See this](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-references) (Work on HTML5 started back in 2004, but it took long time until final publication.)

There's also "XML entity definitions". Although XML is rather old, the official  specification of entities seems to have had been lacking for long.
In its latest version [(2nd ed)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-xml-entity-names-20140410/) in 2014, $\wp$ is [nothing but "weierp"](http://www.w3.org/2003/entities/2007/htmlmathml-f.ent). See [chap 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-xml-entity-names-20140410/#sets). ISOamso is now [one of legacy entity sets](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-xml-entity-names-20140410/#legacysets).  In its [first version](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xml-entity-names-20100401/) in 2010 however, it's classified as [ISOamso](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xml-entity-names-20100401/isoamso.html)

Anyway in ISOamso pages ([ver 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-xml-entity-names-20140410/isoamso.html) and [ver 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xml-entity-names-20100401/isoamso.html)) its description is "/wp - Weierstrass p", with the alias "wp". It seems the slash in "/wp" corresponds to LaTex *backslash*. (Cf. /hbar, /ell, /Re etc)

Unfortunately in MathML 3.0, (the latest, released in 2010) it still depends on XML's "legacy" entity sets, and it [refers to](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-MathML3-20101021/chapter7.html) ISOamso. "Weierstrass'p" is not yet dead.

## "Weierstrass-p" spreaded

The word "Weierstrass p" appears in e.g. [Encyclopedia Machintosh](https://www.google.co.jp/search?tbm=bks&hl=ja&q=isbn%3A9780895886286+%22Weierstrass+p%22) (1990), [MacUser magazine](https://books.google.com/books?id=nIVVAAAAMAAJ&q=%22weierstrass+p%22+letter&dq=%22weierstrass+p%22+letter&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiexquyr7rVAhXI7hoKHbBWCH04HhDoAQglMAA) (1992)

I [googled for](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22weierstrass%27s+p%22+-%22weierstrass%27s+p-function%22&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F1%2F1986&tbm=) `"weierstrass's p" - "weierstrass's p function"` limiting to pre-1986 instances. There had not been any to mean the symbol $\wp$. The result of dropping "'s" is similar. Date limitation in Google search is not so reliable thus it does not prove anything.

Wrong HTML4's specification is now popular. Microsoft's document [HTML Character sets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa212305(v=office.11).aspx) reads "Office 2003", although its exact date and scope are not clear. It says $\wp$ is: "script capital P, =power set, =Weierstrass p, U2118 ISOamso". [XML in a Nutshell](https://books.google.com/books?id=V4o9Tcf2YRoC&pg=PA544&dq=%22Script+capital+P,+power+set,+Weierstrass+p%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Script%20capital%20P%2C%20power%20set%2C%20Weierstrass%20p%22&f=false) (2002) and [Beginning HTML, XHTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://books.google.hu/books?id=vOZLwYJHymQC&pg=PA760&lpg=PA760&dq=Weierstrass+p&source=bl&ots=WtbhJZ9sV2&&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=weierstrass&f=false) (2011) say Weierp is "Script capital P, power set, Weierstrass p"

## Acknowledgments

The books "Encyclopedia Machintosh", "MacUser magazine", "Computer Modern Typeface" and "XML in a Nutshell" were pointed out in Wikipedia Users [Momotaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Weierstrass_p#Cleanup) and [The Man in Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_talk:The_Man_in_Question). I thank them.

## Footnote

In Unicode 1.0.0 (1991), it was **NOT** "script capital p", the current name. In [Unicode Name Index](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode1.0.0/Index1.pdf) (pdf), names  "script p" and "weierstrass elliptic function"  are found. See pdf pages 22 and 27. This did not change in Unicode 1.0.1 (1992).
Unicode 1.0 implicitly, but clearly meant it was capital. All lowercase letters were named "small".

It seems that in Unicode 1.1 (1993) the name was changed to "script *capital* p" See [UnicodeData-1.1.5](http://www.unicode.org/Public/1.1-Update/UnicodeData-1.1.5.txt)

Comment: If Weierstrass popularized approximately this shape of the symbol, and it is based on the letter "p", then what is the problem of calling it "Weierstrass p"?

Answer (score 9):

The Sütterlin alphabeth was introduced by the graphic designer Sütterlin in the 1920s and was the handwriting in German schools 1935-1941. It was a slightly simplified version of Kurrent.
Before that time the usual handwriting style in Germany (since the 1500s) in german language was [Kurrent](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Kurrentschrift) (also known as Kurrentschrift, Alte Deutsche Schrift ("old German script") and German cursive) which was used also in Switzerland till 1900s and in Austria till 1941 (and still taught in schools after 1945; I learned it besides the Ausgangsschrift in elementary school 1955-1959).

The letter $\wp$ is, originally (in my eyes, and as I learned in lecture classes), just a capital P in Kurrent, written in a slightly elaborate way. 
I would say that the Weierstrass-P symbol $\wp$ was introduced by Donald Knuth as a special math TeX-symbol, :) . I would have used $\mathfrak P$ before learning about $\wp$ in the question.

See [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/scanned.html) for six letters by Gauss written in Kurrent.

Comment: Hmm, the Weierstrass -P looks notably different from the Kurrent P in most parts of the letter. Also the references by Francois Ziegler show the use of that very P long before TeX.

Comment: @Dirk No, I think it looks like Kurrent (I saw it in my father's handwriting when a child).

Answer (score 5):

Eugenio Calabi once said in a complex analysis course that it was just Weierstrass's personal way to write lower-case p.  He did not say where he learned that.

Comment: You mean you were there and heard it?